# MinGW: Installation fail

Tags: windows, mingw, sourceforge

I have the following naive question.
Because of my company policy, the pace SourceForge is blocked, therefore I cannot download any tool stored on that page.

The MinGW official page is directly redirecting to SourceForge as the official website for downloads.

My IT-dept has download the mingw-get-setup.exe for me. When I try running it, I get the following errors:

[image]

Do you have a clue what I should change to let the installation keep going and succeed?
I work on a Windows 7 64bit machine.

Comment: I'd try with a "self-contained" MinGW distribution. E.g. [Nuwen MinGW](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) is simple to install and up to date.

Comment: I also do not have access to the link you posted. but thanks for commenting.

Comment: Could there be an issue with the specific installer I am using?

Comment: As far as I know _mingw-get-setup_ will try to download packages from SourceForge (and so will fail). If your IT-dept has downloaded the `mingw-get-setup.exe` file it could also download the Nuwen MinGW installation file (just one big file, no further dependencies).

Comment: Well, as you pointed out, I was expecting that the mingw installer will always try to get dependancies back from SourceForge. For the moment, I'm justing checking whether they can install it for me remotely.